# The tense of the verb in the dependent clause needs to match the main verb's tense? (would or will)

Tags: grammar, verbs, tense-agreement

I get told that #1 is correct and #2 is wrong.

1. They revealed that they would quicken the pace of the change.
2. They revealed that they will quicken the pace of the change.

Is #2 just wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, both constructions are valid. The choice really depends on the context.

Let's imagine that the people who did the revealing did so two years ago and that the pace of the change was quickened one year ago. Then you would naturally write:

> They revealed (two years ago) that they would quicken the pace of the change (last year).

But if the revealing was done last week and the pace of the change is to be quickened next week, you could equally write:

> They revealed (last week) that they will quicken the pace of the change (next week).

In this case, both **would** and **will** can be used. The choice depends on the context and your preference.

The classic example is: **He says the world is round**. Do you then put it into the past tense by saying: **He said the world is round** or **He said the world was round**? There's no absolute rule. Both are valid.

Whoever told you that #2 was wrong is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I too think #2 is valid. But I got confused. It's a grammar checker that told me it's incorrect so it could be that it's giving me a wrong suggestion.